# The target-entity "some entity" cannot be found

Tags: php, doctrine, zend-framework2

i am using ZF2 with doctrine i am getting this error.

> The target-entity Entity\User cannot be found in 'Subject\Entity\Subject#user'.

Here is the snippet to my code.

```
<?php

namespace Subject\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;
/** 

* @ORM\Entity

* @ORM\Table(name="subject")

* @property string $subjectname

* @property int $user_id

* @property int $id

*/
 class Subject implements InputFilterAwareInterface {

  protected $inputFilter;
 /**

 * @ORM\Id

 * @ORM\Column(type="integer");

 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")

 */
protected $id;
/**

 * @ORM\Column(type="string")

 */
protected $subjectname;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity\User", inversedBy="subjects")
 * @var User|null
 */
private $user;

/** @return User|null */
public function getUser() {
    return $this->user;
}

/** @param User $user */
public function setUser(User $user) {
    if($user === null || $user instanceof User) {
        $this->user = $user;
    } else {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$user must be instance of Entity\User or null!');
    }
}}
```

and then my "User" entity

```
namespace Subject\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

/*
* @ORM\Entity

* @ORM\Table(name="users")

* @property string $username

* @property string $password

* @property int $id

*/
class User implements InputFilterAwareInterface {

 protected $_username;
 protected $_password;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Subject", mappedBy="user")
 * @var Collection
 */
private $subjects;

/** @ORM\Id() @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") @var   int */
protected $_id;

public function __get($property) {

    return $this->$property;
}

public function __set($property, $value) {

    $this->$property = $value;
}

//Getters and setters

/** @return Collection */
public function getSubjects() {
    return $this->comments;
}

/** @param Comment $comment */
public function addSubject(Subject $comment) {
    $this->comments->add($comment);
    $comment->setUser($this);
}
```

}

Comment: Refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745924/the-target-entity-cannot-be-found-in-mappingexception

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your entity declaration is incorrect:

```
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entity\User", inversedBy="subjects")
```

This should be either this:

```
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Subject\Entity\User", inversedBy="subjects")
```

Or, since the two classes share the same namespace, you can also use this:

```
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="subjects")
```

The `targetEntity` has to be the fully qualified class name (FQCN), except if referring to a class in the same namespace, in which case the short name may be used (as per the last example above).

Comment: ths for quick answer mate, i followed your edit and now this is what i get 
Class "Subject\Entity\User" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.

Comment: Well, at least it's a different error message, that's always a good sign ;-)

Comment: Oh wow.  One missing asterisk.  The comment containing the annotations must be a _docblock_ comment, which starts with `/**` not `/*`.  Check the first line after the `use` statements in User.php.

Comment: By the way using a good IDE such as phpstorm will highlight these sorts of problems, because you will not get the syntax highlighting you expect if you don't use the docblock comment style.  Plus other things like code completion, refactoring, ctrl-click to definition, etc etc.

Comment: Check you have updated _all_ your `targetEntity` values in all entities, so that they use the correct FQCN.  Also check the error message detail of the new error, it tells you where the problem is (which class and which property).

Comment: Yup the Target entites were not correctly mapped actually i had to fix 2 things 1) Target entites in both files and 2) /** to be used instead of /*, thx you solved my problem

Comment: For a quick feedback regarding your Comment what help can That IDE give , i mean do you personally found it better then Net beans?

Comment: I've never used netbeans much, mainly eclipse-based and more recently phpstorm, but most "proper" IDEs for a given language should be quite comparable for most of the functionality.  However I do find that phpstorm makes clever use of annotations, which can really help when it comes to some of the dynamic features in PHP such as `__call()` and `__get()`.  Anyway, this is a separate discussion I only made that as a side comment!

Comment: i thought that annotation will works here if i use "use" statement but it doesn't work until i passed the full path in annotation

Answer (score 2):

In our case, the file name was not the same as the class name: it was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem in my case was case-sensitivity.

Bad:

```
class Package {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PackagUSA", mappedBy="package")
     */
    private Collection $packageusas;
}

class Packageusa {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Package", inversedBy="packageusas")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="package_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private Package $package;
}
```

Good:

```
class Package {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PackageUSA", mappedBy="package")
     */
    private Collection $packageusas;
}

class PackageUSA {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Package", inversedBy="packageusas")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="package_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private Package $package;
}
```