# doctrine - add joined field to results

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Symfony (3.0.3) app, I have a table:

```
 CRM_FORM_RESPONSE(form_response_id int, form_id int, company_id int, response text)
```

where I store responses from Companies to small Forms (i.e. questionnaires)
 Until now I've been retrieving these via Doctrine as follows:

```
$qb = $doc->getEntityManager ()->createQueryBuilder ();
$query = $qb->select ( 'u' )->from ( 'AppBundle:CrmFormResponse', 'u' )->getQuery();
$result = $query->getResult ();
```

Now, I'd like to add the name of the Company to the resultset, where the foreign table is:

CRM_COMPANY(comapny_id int, companyname text);

So, my question is about the best-practices for achieving this in Doctrine..

- Should I create a View that JOINs CrmCompany and selects the extra
  column? Or just modify the DQL
- Should I add COMPANYNAME to the AppBundle/CrmFormResponse entity class?  Even though it's not really a member of the table?

Is there a standard practice in this (common) scenario that avoids these measures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using doctrine, you should speak of objects instead of table:
Do you have a mapping which allows you to do `CrmFormResponse->getCrmCompany`?
You should add the mapping of CrmCompany in CrmFormResponse entity this way:

In CrmFormResponse.php

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="CrmCompany")
 */
 $crmCompany
```

Then, the query should be

```
$query = $qb
      ->select('u')
      ->from ('AppBundle:CrmFormResponse', 'u')
      ->addSelect('company')
      ->innerJoin('u.crmCompany', 'company')
      ->getQuery();
```

And you get the company name by using

```
$entityCrmFormResponse->getCompany()->getName()
```

EDIT: Note than you don't need to change your query to do that, but my query with the `join` and the `addSelect` avoid you to do extra queries each time you use `$entityCrmFormResponse->getCompany()`

Comment: thanks for that; but I get `request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: "The target-entity AppBundle\CrmCompany cannot be found in 'AppBundle\Entity\CrmFormResponse#crmCompany'." at /Users/user/Sites/crm/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php line 762 ` - even if I specify the fully qualified name for CrmCompany.   Any ideas?

Comment: Have you created an entity CrmCompany? does that entity has a `/** @Entity`? maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/14707690/2235811